# Evaluating$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^7-1}}\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve several integrals similar to this $$\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^7-1}}\,\mathrm dx$$
 I don't how to proceed because by parts method will not help me and I can't figure a good subtitution to solve it. Can you help me? Thanks you in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an obvious substitution!
$$\sqrt{x^7-1}=t\iff\frac{7x^6}{2\sqrt{x^7-1}}\,\mathrm dx=\,\mathrm dt$$

$$x^7=t^2+1$$
$$I=\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^7-1}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac27\int\frac{1}{1+t^2}\,\mathrm \,\mathrm dt=\frac27\arctan(t)+c$$

> $$\large\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{x^7-1}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{2}{7}\arctan(\sqrt{x^7-1})+c$$

Comment: Lol, the substitution was in front of me... thank you

Comment: (But really, for nice answer.)